Solr exception Invalid Date String:'1623172346000' when the date field is in highlight
I was using solr 6.6 and now trying to upgrade to 7.3.
I have data with ID, Name, CreatedDate and some other fields. When I am running query (query is on ID), and include the date field in highlight list, it throws the exception:
 o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Date String:'1623172346000'
    at org.apache.solr.util.DateMathParser.parseMath(DateMathParser.java:247)
    at org.apache.solr.util.DateMathParser.parseMath(DateMathParser.java:226)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.DatePointField.toNativeType(DatePointField.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.DatePointField.readableToIndexed(DatePointField.java:184)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.PointField.toInternalByteRef(PointField.java:193)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType$DefaultAnalyzer$1.incrementToken(FieldType.java:492)
    at org.apache.solr.highlight.TokenOrderingFilter.incrementToken(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:809)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.OffsetLimitTokenFilter.incrementToken(OffsetLimitTokenFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.CachingTokenFilter.fillCache(CachingTokenFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.CachingTokenFilter.incrementToken(CachingTokenFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex.storeTerms(MemoryIndex.java:583)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex.addField(MemoryIndex.java:474)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex.addField(MemoryIndex.java:452)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex.addField(MemoryIndex.java:431)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.WeightedSpanTermExtractor.getLeafContext(WeightedSpanTermExtractor.java:405)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.WeightedSpanTermExtractor.extractWeightedTerms(WeightedSpanTermExtractor.java:364)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.WeightedSpanTermExtractor.extract(WeightedSpanTermExtractor.java:141)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.WeightedSpanTermExtractor.extract(WeightedSpanTermExtractor.java:112)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.WeightedSpanTermExtractor.getWeightedSpanTerms(WeightedSpanTermExtractor.java:513)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.QueryScorer.initExtractor(QueryScorer.java:218)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.QueryScorer.init(QueryScorer.java:186)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.Highlighter.getBestTextFragments(Highlighter.java:201)
    at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlightingByHighlighter(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:631)
    at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlightingOfField(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlighting(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:442)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent.process(HighlightComponent.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:295)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:195)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:711)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:517)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:384)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1629)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

The error was not coming in 6.6.
I am importing the data from SQL using dataimporter. The dates are passed in format of "2021-06-08T17:12:26Z"
I am suspecting this has something to do with highlighter trying to transform the dates.
EDIT:
Forgot to mention, the field is a datepoint field as below:
<fieldType name="date" class="solr.DatePointField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0" />

<field name="CreationDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>


The highlighter component only works with tokenized fields (ie. a tokenizer must be defined in the fieldType), and tokenizers only work with text fields, that is, solr.TextField or solr.SortableTextField. In 6.6 maybe you were just retrieving the field value (using fl parameter) rather than highlighting it (with hl.fl) ? Or you were using another field with the date indexed as text ?
